# How to get the same loss value, every time training a CNN (MNIST data set), with TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I want to train a convolutional neural network (with MNIST data set and TensorFlow) a few times new and get every time the same results of the accuracy. To get this i:

1. Save an untrained only initialized (global_variables_initializer) net
2. Load every time I start the training this untrained net
3. Set mnist.train.next_batch shuffle=False, so the image sequence is every time the same

I have done this before with a feed forward net (3 hidden layer) and every time I run this python script I get the exact same values for loss and accuracy.

**But,** the "same" script with changing the model from a feed forward net to a convolutional neural net make every time I run the script a little different loss/accuracy.

So I reduce the batch size to one and look for each image the loss value and see that the first two images always have the same loss value, but the rest is every time I run the script a little different.

Any idea why?

Comment: Did you add dropout layer?

Comment: Are you building the conv layers yourself or using the built-in conv2d layers?

Comment: @danche first i had dropout but at the moment i have removed it

Comment: @OferSadan i use tf.nn.conv2d

Comment: Some tensorflow operations (convolution and reductions, for example) are non-deterministic because of details of the GPU implementation.

Comment: @AlexandrePassos so you mean it is something what tensorflow is doing and I can not do anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AlexandrePassos comment, I search for deterministic/ non-deterministic operations in TensorFlow.

So at the moment all operations which using CUDA atomics and running on GPU, are non-deterministic.
See this link: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3103

If somebody knows a way to realize a CNN with TensorFlow on GPU and with deterministic operations, please: [How to create a CNN with deterministic operations in TensorFlow on a GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800055/how-to-create-a-cnn-with-deterministic-operations-in-tensorflow-on-a-gpu)